# Creating a Javascript function that returns random integers but with a specified distribution/"weight"

Tags: javascript, probability, non-uniform-distribution

I have an array of values:

```
var my_arr = [/*all kinds of stuff*/]
```

I have a function that generates a random number, which I use as the index of an element in `my_arr`...

```
var RandomFromRange = function (min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
};
```

...so I could do stuff like this:

```
my_arr[RandomFromRange(0,my_arr.length)];
```

What I want to do is to designate certain elements within `my_arr` as having "priority", so that `RandomFromRange` returns 5, say, 25% of the time, returns 4, 14% of the time, and returns any other number...

```
(100 - 25 - 14)/(my_arr.length - 2)
```

...% of the time.

As I was doing my research, I came across several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783133/function-that-returns-integer-with-specific-distribution) [that describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207272/random-values-with-non-uniform-distribution) [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094873/how-to-implement-non-uniform-probability-distribution), but their answers are not in Javascript, and I, alas, don't have enough math to understand their general principles. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're interested in understanding this then i recommend reading http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/ which came about from this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027757/data-structure-for-loaded-dice

Comment: The javascript sources for the @david link is [here](http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/js/alias.js).

Comment: Many thanks for the references, dhilt and david.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be as exact as what you are looking for, but this certainly works. Basically this code returns a random number specified from the min and max like yours, but only after addressing the priority numbers based on the chance given.

First we gotta *prioritize* your priority numbers in the code. If there is no hit on your priority numbers, that is when we proceed to the normal RNG.

```js
//priority = list of numbers as priority,
//chance = the percentage
//min and max are your parameters

var randomFromRange = function (min,max,priority,chance)
{
  var val = null; //initialize value to return
 
 for(var i = 0; i < priority.length; i++){ //loop through priority numbers
  
  var roll = Math.floor(Math.random()*100); //roll the dice (outputs 0-100)
  
  if(chance > roll){ ///check if the chance is greater than the roll output, if true, there's a hit. Less chance value means less likely that the chance value is greater than the roll output
   val = priority[i]; //make the current number in the priority loop the value to return;
   break; //if there's a hit, stop the loop.
  }
  else{
   continue; //else, keep looping through the priority list
  }
 }
 
  //if there is no hit to any priority numbers, return a number from the min and max range
 if(val == null){
  val = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
 }
 
  //return the value and do whatever you want with it
 return val;
};

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = function (){
 console.log(randomFromRange(0,10,[20,30],50));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style='height: 1000px; width: 100%;'></body>
<script></script>
</html>
```

This code applies a single chance on all array of priority numbers. If you want individual chances for each number in the priority list, we gotta modify the structure and change parameters to a single array of objects that holds something like

```
var priorityList = [{num: 4, chance: 25},
                    {num: 5, chance: 12}]
```

etc

Comment: Merigold, I just wanted to thank you for providing a solution to my question. I have successfully implemented your code, with minimal modifications.

Comment: Glad to help bud